# Android OpenGL using both Java and C++

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

Can you blend Java and native OpenGL calls. For instance having the setup happen in the onSurfaceCreated, but having the onDraw call into native code (or even both)? I'm having trouble getting native code to render, but can't tell if this could be a problem or if I'm throwing c++ exceptions, but they don't bubble up...

```
    private static native void drawFromJni();

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    try{
        drawFromJni();
       //gl.glDrawArrays... also
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("sv", ex.getMessage());
    }
} 

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10);
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
     gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
     gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
     gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
     gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
     gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer is yes, it works.